# Show custom message after booting process finishes and displays boot log instead of Ubuntu logo

Tags: 14.04, boot, plymouth

I want to remove boot up logo and to show booting process instead of Ubuntu logo.

This can be done by:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then look for the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It may have other options there as well, but just remove `quiet splash`, next update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Also I want to add a massage like "hello dipesh ubuntu start" at the end of booting process. How?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is to put as the last line in the `AUTOEXEC.BAT` file `ECHO Booting finished`.  On a single-user, single-tasking OS, this is quite simple.  On a multi-user, multi-tasking OS this just doesn't make sense as multiple processes are still being executed when the Linux init process (aka "boot process" in other OSes) will come to *the last command to start*.

*But*, you're asking, we're answering:

Go to the /etc/rc6.d  and create a shell script with a file name higher in alphabetical order then the last one you find and put the following lines in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello Dipesh, Ubuntu start has probably not finished yet, but here you are...
```

P.S. Don't forget to read `/etc/rc6.d/README` as to *why* it doesn't make sense.